# Scipy sparse matrix: boolean combinations of columns

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to combine columns of a sparse (binary) array using a boolean operation in Scipy (v0.18.1). For a dense matrix it works fine to do:

```
data[:,5] & ~data[:,23] & data[:,400]
```

Which collapses into a single column. However I get an error when doing this with a sparse array.

Error for the boolean part:

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'csc_matrix' and 'csc_matrix'"
```

Error for the ~ (inversion) part:

```
bad operand type for unary ~: 'csc_matrix'
```

Comment: You may have to convert the slice to dense before applying unary `~`. Inverting a sparse matrix would give a (probably _very_) dense matrix anyway.

Comment: @LucaCiti Good point! They probably didn't implement it for performance (and consistency) reasons, cause the complement of a sparse matrix isn't really sparse anymore.

Comment: @LucaCiti Okay, though maybe I can do a trick with checking against the nonzero elements. What about the boolean part?

Comment: @cgreen see my answer

Answer (score 0):

One can use elementwise multiplication `a.multiply(b)` ("and") and addition `a+b` ("or") between sparse boolean matrices to implement binary operations. Concerning the negation `~`, it may be worth converting the slice to dense since the negation of a sparse matrix would give a (probably very) dense matrix anyway. In some cases, careful use of De Morgan's laws may make a significant difference and help avoid (or reduce) the need of such conversions if at all possible.

A possible trick for `data[:,5] & ~data[:,23]` could be `data[:,5] > data[:,23]`.

`data[:,5] & ~data[:,23] & data[:,400]` could be written as `(data[:,5] > data[:,23]).multiply(data[:,400])` although it is not very readable.

Comment: I tried various combinations on a (1000,1000) matrix, and found that simply indexing the 3 columns dominates the timings.

Comment: @hpaulj Possibly, but that's a rather small matrix and using dense matrices may actually be faster. I imagine the type of situation that could come up in natural language processing with a document-term matrix that could easily be several millions (e.g. of tweets) by thousands (of words). I haven't tried but in that case I guess never converting to dense makes a big difference.